# xarg, find and rm rm: cannot remove `./not': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, find, xargs, rm

I am following [this Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) to find and remove a file.

```
[jalal@galapagos-04] (5)$ touch 'not important_file'
[jalal@galapagos-04] (6)$ touch important_file
[jalal@galapagos-04] (7)$ ls
agreement.txt    cs_web          johns.txt            reverse_sorted_user.txt  songs.txt        users.txt*
awk_example.txt  good_users.txt  marks.txt            sed_example.txt          sorted_user.txt
cs.html          important_file  not\ important_file  softlink/                test@
[jalal@galapagos-04] (8)$ find . -name not\* | tail -1 | xargs rm
rm: cannot remove `./not': No such file or directory
```

Any idea how could this be fixed?

Comment: Note that `important_file`  is now gone!

Answer (score 2):

The `xargs` article you link to discusses in detail how using null or line-terminated processing is needed to handle these exact situations, but you're not even using `xargs`.

You've copied an example that's mean to illustrate something that doesn't work.